# Why is RichText not working in wagtail admin for posts? This is the type of thing that happens: <h2>Trying post.content|richtext</h2>

Tags: python, django, wagtail, richtext

Wagtail implemented on an existing Django site. I have included the parts of code most likely to contain the error.  If you would like anything else please do not hesitate to request it.  Code as follows:
models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject_slug = models.SlugField(editable=True, max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('subject', kwargs=kwargs)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.subject
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('subject'),
        FieldPanel('subject_slug')
    ]
    
    class Meta:
        # Gives the proper plural name for class called subject
        verbose_name_plural = "Subjects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='blog_posts')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, verbose_name='Subject', default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=True, max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.title
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('author'),
        FieldPanel('subject'),
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
        FieldPanel('content')
    ]
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    made_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['made_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

index.htm

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
  {{ post.content|richtext }}
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.subject.subject_slug post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>author: {{post.author}}, published: {{post.date_added }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

wagtail_hooks.py

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, ModelAdminGroup, modeladmin_register)

from .models import (
    Subject, Post, Comment)

class SubjectAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Subject
    menu_label = 'Subjects'    from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, ModelAdminGroup, modeladmin_register)

from .models import (
    Subject, Post, Comment)

class SubjectAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Subject
    menu_label = 'Subjects'
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'
    list_display = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    list_filter = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    search_fields = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'subject_slug': ['subject'],}

class PostAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    menu_label = 'Post'
    menu_icon = 'author'
    list_display = ('subject', 'title', 'slug','date_added', 'author')
    list_filter = ('subject', 'date_added',)
    search_fields = ('subject', 'title', 'content', 'author')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title'],}
    
modeladmin_register(SubjectAdmin)
modeladmin_register(PostAdmin)
    menu_icon = 'pilcrow'
    list_display = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    list_filter = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    search_fields = ('subject', 'subject_slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'subject_slug': ['subject'],}

class PostAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    menu_label = 'Post'
    menu_icon = 'author'
    list_display = ('subject', 'title', 'slug','date_added', 'author')
    list_filter = ('subject', 'date_added',)
    search_fields = ('subject', 'title', 'content', 'author')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title'],}
    
modeladmin_register(SubjectAdmin)
modeladmin_register(PostAdmin)
```

The machine wants more details.  I'm not sure what else I can say other than this is what I don't want in my posts:

### Heading H2

**Bold** and not bold

#### ***H3 bold and italic for fun***

Comment: What URL are you actually visiting to view the template? Is it a view that you've written - if so, can you post the view code?

Comment: In the template, the line `{{ post.content|richtext }}` is outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gasman, the way I fixed it was I implemented post.content|richtext  and loaded wagtailcore_tags in templates and it works!